# Derivation of the gradient expansion of the Keldysh nonlinear sigma model for disorder metals

Tags: condensed-matter, greens-functions, disorder

My confusion relates to Appendix C of this [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.3586) although the same derivation is presented in many others.
When deriving the gradient expansion of this term arrives at a term quadratic in the scalar potential, which takes the form $\mathrm{Tr}V^\alpha \Upsilon^{\alpha\beta} V^\beta$ where $\alpha,\beta \in \{\mathrm{c}l, \mathrm{q}\}$ are indices in the Keldysh matrix space, the trace is over space and time indices, and
$$\Upsilon^{\alpha\beta}(\omega) = - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\mathbf{p}} \mathrm{Tr}_K \mathcal{G}(\mathbf{p}, \epsilon+\omega/2)\gamma^\alpha\mathcal{G}(\mathbf{p}, \epsilon-\omega/2)\gamma^\beta$$
with $\mathrm{Tr}_K$ the trace over Fermionic Keldysh indices, $\gamma^{cl} = \sigma^0$, $\gamma^q=\sigma^1$ are matrices in the Fermionic Keldysh space, and $\mathcal{G}$ is the disorder averaged Fermionic Green's function.
In particular, we write the Fermionic Green's function as 
$$\hat{\mathcal{G}} = \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{G}^R \left(1 + \hat{\Lambda}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{G}^A \left(1 - \hat{\Lambda}\right)$$
where $\mathcal{G}^{R(A)} = [\epsilon - \xi \pm \frac{i}{2\tau}]^{-1}$ is the retarded (advanced) disorder averaged Green's function and $\Lambda$ is the stationary saddle point solution of the non-linear sigma model
$$\hat{\Lambda} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1^R&2F\\
0&-1^A
\end{pmatrix}$$
c.f. Eq. 165.
This expression is then evaluated to be $i\nu \hat{\sigma}_1^{\alpha\beta}$ where $\sigma_1$ is the first Pauli matrix in the bosonic Keldysh space and $\nu$ is the density of states at the Fermi surface.

So far so good. My confusion is the decision in Appendix C to only include the products $\mathcal{G}^R\mathcal{G}^R$ or $\mathcal{G}^A\mathcal{G}^A$ in the integral. Using the above parametrization of the Keldysh Green's function one can see that $\Upsilon^{\mathrm{cl},\mathrm{cl}}=0$ but each of the other components are not identically zero and contain $(\mathcal{G}^R)^2$, $(\mathcal{G}^A)^2$, and $\mathcal{G}^R\mathcal{G}^A$ terms.
I don't follow the argument for why only the R-R terms should be included and in fact in the other parts of the gradient expansion it is instead the R-A terms which are kept and the R-R and A-A terms vanish due to the analytic structure of the Green's functions.
Furthermore, it is not clear to me why the q-q component is zero.
Am I missing something about the analytical structure of the integrands or is there a physical argument for this?

Comment: What do you mean ? The $\gamma$ matrices select any component of the $G$'s, aren't they ? I do not understand the notations : $\gamma^{\alpha,\beta}$ on one side, and $\gamma^{cl,q}$ on the other ... It should be $\gamma^{\alpha}\equiv\sigma_{\alpha}$, the Pauli matrices in Keldysh space, isn't it ?

Comment: @FraSchelle I'm sorry, the original phrasing was unclear. I have modified it to hopefully improve the readability. In particular the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ indices run over cl, q indexing the classical and quantum components of the field $V$. In particular, using the parametrization $\hat{\mathcal{G}} = \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{G}^R \left(1 + \hat{\Lambda}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\mathcal{G}^A \left(1 - \hat{\Lambda}\right)$ each non-zero component of $\Upsilon$ contains products of $(\mathcal{G}^{R/A})^2$ and $\mathcal{G}^R\mathcal{G}^A$ but explicitly only the former are kept.